# JPA + Hibernate Mechanism

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I started working with **JPA - Hibernate projects**, but I didn't get how the internal mechanism between **JPA and Hibernate** is going on.

Can any one pls share your opinion.

Comment: What do you mean by the term flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate is an implementation of the [JPA specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr317/). Hibernate's implementation goes further than simply implementing the spec, often introducing features that will eventually be adopted by JPA in later specifications.

There are other JPA implementations, the most prominent being [EclipseLink](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/jpa.php). It is also the reference implementation for JPA 2.0 and 2.1 specs.

To answer your question more precisely - there is no flow, as JPA and Hibernate are two different things, JPA being a specification (an API) and Hibernate the implementation of this spec.